# How to approach searching for sources of interface unresponsiveness

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel, latency

On Debian Linux:

On a relatively powerful machine I ran an update and both the kernel and the window manager got updated to newer version. At that point the machine become noticeably less responsive: every few seconds while scrolling or watching video it freezes for less than a tenth of a second. Overall performance does not suffer, just the subjective "latency" is now noticeable.

How should I approach debugging such an issue? What knobs does the kernel provide for manipulating "subjective interface latency"?